# Method chunk does not exist when i'm importing excel file

Tags: php, excel, laravel, import

I'm trying to import 100k data to database from excel and i'm having timeout problems so i used the chunk method but it says "chunk method does not exist".
How can i fix this problem?

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($request->file('excelFile')->chunk(900, 
function ($reader) use ($electionId, &$voterCount, &$lastVoter,&$rowError) 
{
     foreach ($reader->toArray()[0] as $row) {
     $voter                  = new Voter();
     $voter->electionId      = $electionId;
     $voter->voterNumber     = $row['voter_id'];
     $voter->name            = $row['name'];
     $voter->password        = $row['password'] === 
     null || $row['password'] == '' ? rand(1,100000) : $row['password'];
     $voter->emailAddress    = $row['email'];
     $voter->mobileNumber    = $row['mobile_number'];



     }
     }));
```

Comment: one bracket missing in after load method you haven't close bracket )

Comment: @pal it's on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded dealer detail. Try this, This is working in my case :

```
public function addDealerByAdmin(Request $request_body)
{ 

    if ($request_body->hasFile('file')) {
            //if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == "text/csv" || $csv_file_type = array('text/csv')) {

            $file_array = Input::file('file');
            $file_name = $file_array->getClientOriginalName();

            //Log::info('file_type : ', ['file_type' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'file_ext' => File::extension($file_name)]);

            if (File::extension($file_name) == 'csv') {
                // Good to go

                $csv_file_type = array('text/csv');
                $csvMimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel');
                $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $csvFile = fopen($filename, 'r');
                //skip first line
                fgetcsv($csvFile);
                DB::beginTransaction();
                $i = 2;
                //parse data from csv file line by line
                DB::delete('DELETE FROM dealer_master');
                while (($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE) {
                    $company_name = isset($line[0]) ? $line[0] : '';
                    $address_line_1 = isset($line[1]) ? $line[1] : '';
                    $city = isset($line[2]) ? $line[2] : '';
                    $state_or_province = isset($line[3]) ? $line[3] : '';
                    $zip_or_postal_code = isset($line[4]) ? $line[4] : '';
                    $phone = isset($line[5]) ? $line[5] : '';
                    $client_id = isset($line[6]) ? $line[6] : '';
                    $sales_representative = isset($line[7]) ? $line[7] : '';
                    $dealer_OEM_franchise = isset($line[8]) ? $line[8] : '';

                    $validation_data = array(
                        'company_name' => $company_name,
                        'address_line_1' => $address_line_1,
                        'city' => $city,
                        'state_or_province' => $state_or_province,
                        'zip_or_postal_code' => $zip_or_postal_code,
                    );

                    //Log::info('validation', ['validation' => $validation_data]);
                    // (new VerificationController())->required_validation($validation_data, $i);
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach ($validation_data as $key => $value) {
                        if (empty($value)) {
                            //return Response::json(array('code' => '201', 'message' => 'Please enter ' . $key . ' at line ' . $i . '.', 'cause' => '', 'response' => json_decode("{}")));
                            $count = $count + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if ($count == 0) {

                        $data = array(
                            'company_name' => $company_name,
                            'address_line_1' => $address_line_1,
                            'city' => $city,
                            'state_or_province' => $state_or_province,
                            'zip_or_postal_code' => $zip_or_postal_code,
                            'phone' => $phone,
                            'client_id' => $client_id,
                            'sales_representative' => $sales_representative,
                            'dealer_OEM_franchise' => $dealer_OEM_franchise,
                            'is_active' => 1,
                            'create_time' => $create_time
                        );
                        DB::beginTransaction();


                        $dealer_id = DB::table('dealer_master')->insertGetId($data);

                        DB::commit();

                    }

                    $i++;


                }
                //$i++;
                DB::commit();
                //close opened csv file
                fclose($csvFile);
                $response = Response::json(array('code' => '200', 'message' => 'Dealer added successfully.', 'cause' => '', 'response' => json_decode("{}")));

            } else {
                //Log::info('file_type', ['file_type' => $_FILES['file']['type']]);
                return $response = Response::json(array('code' => '201', 'message' => 'You can upload only CSV file.', 'cause' => '', 'response' => json_decode("{}")));
            }

        } else {
            return $response = Response::json(array('code' => '201', 'message' => 'Required field file is missing or empty.', 'cause' => '', 'response' => json_decode("{}")));
        }
}
```

Comment: I have uploaded 19K entry at a one time. but I thought You should try this.